# General question about SmartSheet API and creating a user interface

Tags: smartsheet-api

My company keeps individual employee schedules.  Each employee manages their own schedule.   Admin,supervisors and project manager have to go to each sheet and look for the information.

I need to create a system that allows someone to select a date range and skill set then produce a sheet with the information that matches the criteria.   I have installed the Python API and worked through a few tutorials.

Now I need to know how to make command buttons, date pickers . . .

A quick read of my search results indicates that this is not part of the Smartsheet API!

Is there a way to do this through the SmartSheet API?   Or how would you approach this?

Answer (score 1):

The Smartsheet API enables you to programmatically access data in Smartsheet (i.e., create, read, update, delete data in Smartsheet). This is true for all APIs -- they simply provide a means for you to programmatically access data. You'll need to build the web app's user interface (UI) yourself by using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.

Alternatively -- instead of building a custom web application like you've described -- I'd suggest that you look into the possibility of creating [Smartsheet Reports](https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/522214-creating-reports) that can provide the data you've described. You can create Smartsheet Reports via the Smartsheet UI -- so you wouldn't need to do any programming at all.